# Returning empty tk Entry box to previous state when clicked away from

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently developing my first python program, a booking system using tkinter. I have a customer account creation screen that uses a number of Entry boxes. When the Entry box is clicked the following  key bind is called to clear the entry box of its instruction (ie. "enter name")

```
def entry_click(event):
  if "enter" in event.widget.get():
     event.widget.delete(0, "end")
     event.widget.insert(0, "")
     event.widget.configure(fg="white")

#example Entry fields
new_name = Entry(root)
new_name.insert(0, "enter name")
new_name.bind('<FocusIn>', entry_click)
new_name.bind('<FocusOut>', entry_focusout)

new_email = Entry(root)
new_email.insert(0, "enter email")
new_email.bind('<FocusIn>', entry_click)
new_email.bind('<FocusOut>', entry_focusout)
```

In a similar vein I'm looking for a way to create a universal  event where the appropriate text for that unique entry field is returned to its initial state (ie. "enter first name" or "enter email") if the box is empty when clicked away from.

```
def entry_focusout():
if not event.widget.get():
   event.widget.insert(fg="grey")
   event.widget.insert(0, #[appropriate text here])
```

How would I be able to do this?
Many thanks.

Comment: I need the same function to also work for new_email, for instance, where the case would be .insert(0, "enter email") - the text that needs to be returned to the Entry is not universal and needs to be different for each Entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an arg to your `entry_focusout` event and bind to the `Entry` widgets with a lambda function.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def entry_click(event):
  if event.widget["foreground"] == "grey":
     event.widget.delete(0, "end")
     event.widget.insert(0, "")
     event.widget.configure(fg="black")

def entry_focusout(event, msg):
    if not event.widget.get():
       event.widget.configure(fg="grey") #you had a typo here
       event.widget.insert(0, msg)

new_name = Entry(root,fg="grey")
new_name.insert(0, "enter name")
new_name.bind('<FocusIn>', entry_click)
new_name.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda e: entry_focusout(e, "enter name"))

new_email = Entry(root,fg="grey")
new_email.insert(0, "enter email")
new_email.bind('<FocusIn>', entry_click)
new_email.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda e: entry_focusout(e, "enter email"))

new_name.pack()
new_email.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This `if "enter" in ...` is **error prone**, the `Entry` could have `'enter'` as part of the data.

Comment: Yes, but that is his logic and i'm leaving it as is. For me i'll probably use `if event.widget.get() == "enter name"`

Comment: You are right, my comment should have go to the Question. **Thanks** for the **simple** solution.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Return empty `tk.Entry` box to previous state when clicked away

The following is a `OOP` **universal** solution.
Thanks to @Henry Yik, for the `if event.widget["foreground"] == "grey":` part.

```
class EntryInstruction(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, instruction=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.instruction = instruction

        self.focus_out(None)
        self.bind('<FocusIn>', self.focus_in)
        self.bind('<FocusOut>', self.focus_out)

    def focus_in(self, event):
        if self["foreground"] == "grey":
            self.delete(0, "end")
            self.configure(fg="black")

    def focus_out(self, event):
        if not self.get():
            self.configure(fg="grey")
            self.insert(0, self.instruction)
```

> **Usage**:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        entry = EntryInstruction(self, '<enter name>')
        entry.grid(row=0, column=0)

        entry = EntryInstruction(self, '<enter email>')
        entry.grid(row=1, column=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***