# Keep placeholder after typing and deleting something in a python Tkinter Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code:

```
date.insert(0, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
date.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda args: history_Date_Entry.delete('0', 'end'))
```

How can I make the placeholder visible after someone type on it and delete the text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning empty tk Entry box to previous state when clicked away from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55327900/returning-empty-tk-entry-box-to-previous-state-when-clicked-away-from)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try:
    from tkinter import *  # Python 3.x
except ImportError:
    from Tkinter import *  # Python 2.x

root = Tk()
e = Entry(root)
e1 = Entry(root) # dummy one
e.insert(0, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
e.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda args: e.delete('0', 'end'))
e.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda args: e.insert('0', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
e.pack()
e1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do, is:

First import `tkinterpp` like this:

```
import tkinterpp
```

Then for the code:

```py
your_entry= tkinterpp.EntryWithPlaceholder(your_window, placeholder="jj/mm/aaaa")
```